# Trouble with VBA Right-Click Paste

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a Pop Up Menu to paste into an ActiveX Textbox on an Excel worksheet. The pop up works but the "Paste" option is grayed out.

```
Private Sub txtInput_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If Button = vbKeyRButton Then
        Call ShowMenu
        Application.CommandBars("MyMenu").ShowPopup
    End If
End Sub



Sub ShowMenu()
    'Remove any old instance of MyPopUp
    On Error Resume Next
    CommandBars("MyMenu").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    With CommandBars.Add(name:="MyMenu", Position:=msoBarPopup)
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=22)
            .Enabled = True
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I added in the `.Enabled = True` but that did not fix the issue. I'm sure I'm missing something basic.

Additional question, once the user *can* click paste, do I HAVE to add `OnAction` and refer to a sub to have it actually paste the text into the textbox or is using the msoControlButton with ID 22 enough to indicate the pasting of text?

Answer (score 1):

> Additional question, once the user can click paste, do I HAVE to add OnAction and refer to a sub to have it actually paste the text into the textbox or is using the msoControlButton with ID 22 enough to indicate the pasting of text?

No, you actually don't need to use either, because the `ActiveX TextBox` class has a `Paste` method which you can use. So, piggy-backing on @Mukul Varney's answer, within the `cmdPasteButton_Click` event procedure, you can simply do:

```
txtInput.Paste
```

And this should paste the clipboard contents at the cursor position in the TextBox.

```
Private Sub cmdPasteButton_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)
    txtInput.Paste

    CancelDefault = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the `txtInput.Paste` as it is necessary to paste the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try below. Paste is enabled for me.

```
Private WithEvents cmdPasteButton As CommandBarButton

Private Sub txtInput_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If Button = vbKeyRButton Then
        Call ShowMenu
        Application.CommandBars("MyMenu").ShowPopup
    End If
End Sub

Sub ShowMenu()

    'Remove any old instance of MyPopUp
    On Error Resume Next
    CommandBars("MyMenu").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set cmdPasteButton = CommandBars.Add(Name:="MyMenu", Position:=msoBarPopup).Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=22)
    cmdPasteButton.OnAction = "Textbox_Paste"

End Sub

Private Sub cmdPasteButton_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)
    MsgBox "hello from cmdPasteButton_Click"
    CancelDefault = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If this refers to another procedure such as `"Textbox_Paste"` you may want to include the necessary code from that procedure, too. Otherwise I think this answer would be incomplete.

Comment: @DavidZemens, Added the code to show a message box when Paste is clicked.

Comment: Your `OnAction` statement is calling the `"Textbox_Paste"` procedure. Where is the code for `"Textbox_Paste"`?

Comment: @DavidZemens, I have left it for you to try. :-). I have given enough suggestions in my answer to solve the problem.

Comment: You're explicitly calling a procedure for which you are not providing the code (and is not part of the OP). Either this `OnAction` is irrelevant, in which case you should omit the statement from your answer, or it is relevant, in which case your answer is incomplete. Further, while your code does provide an active `Paste` button, it doesn't actually perform the paste operation, and your solution doesn't address: *do I HAVE to add OnAction and refer to a sub to have it actually paste the text into the textbox or is using the msoControlButton with ID 22 enough?*

Comment: @MukulVarshney thank you for the help. Using your answer and David Zemens' answer has enabled the paste and I can now paste content into the textbox